# SQL query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query in the model of CI. I need to make this query short. I need to get the first five builders name for each alphabet. Is there any way to make it shorter?

**Model**

```
public function getBuilders() {        
    $query1 = $this->db->select('builder_name')->from('builders_list')->where('builder_name like', 'a%')->limit('5')->get();
    $query2 = $this->db->select('builder_name')->from('builders_list')->where('builder_name like', 'b%')->limit('5')->get();
    $query3 = $this->db->select('builder_name')->from('builders_list')->where('builder_name like', 'c%')->limit('5')->get();
    $query4 = $this->db->select('builder_name')->from('builders_list')->where('builder_name like', 'd%')->limit('5')->get();
    $query5 = $this->db->select('builder_name')->from('builders_list')->where('builder_name like', 'e%')->limit('5')->get();
    $query6 = $this->db->select('builder_name')->from('builders_list')->where('builder_name like', 'f%')->limit('5')->get();
    $result1 = $query1->result();
    $result2 = $query2->result();
    $result3 = $query3->result();
    $result4 = $query4->result();
    $result5 = $query5->result();
    $result6 = $query6->result();
    return array($result1, $result2, $result3, $result4, $result5, $result6); 
}
```

Comment: Post your plain SQL query too. Some SQL experts who don't know CI also can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$this->db->select('builder_name')
         ->from('builders_list')
         ->like('name','a%')
         ->or_like('name','b%')
         ->or_like('name','c%')
         ->or_like('name','d%')
         ->or_like('name','e%')
         ->or_like('name','f%')
         ->limit(5)
         ->get();
```

Comment: I would also add a order by name ASC so that the A's and B's would be all together.

Comment: this won't work as the OP expects. The OP needs the first five results for each initial (30 total). This suggestion produces the first 5 results among all the listed initials (5 total)

Comment: hi i am getting this result with not query why are coming not in this query SELECT `builder_name` FROM `builders_list` WHERE `builder_name` LIKE '%a!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%b!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%c!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%d!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%e!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%f!%%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 5

Answer (score 0):

You may shorten the code a bit by making multiple calls to the model.

in the controller:

```
$initials = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
foreach ($initials as $initial)
{
  $result = $this->model->getBuilders($initial);

  // here you do something with the data that's returned in $result
}
```

in the model:

```
public function getBuilders($initial)
{
$query = $this->db->select('builder_name')->from('builders_list')->where('builder_name like', $initial.'%')->limit('5')->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

So, for each initial, you'll hit the model, which will return 5 results for that initial. Do whatever you need with those and the foreach will then loop to the next initial and will keep going until the last initial has been queried.

Answer (score 0):

You may use . Wildcard % after for a% and also other you want to find, you can use

```
$query1 = $this->db->select('builder_name')
         ->from('builders_list')
         ->like('name','a','after')
         ->or_like('name','b','after')
         ->or_like('name','c','after')
         ->or_like('name','d','after')
         ->or_like('name','e','after')
         ->or_like('name','f','after')
         ->limit(5)
         ->get();
return $query1->result();
```

Thank You

Comment: This won't produce the result the OP expects as the query will output at most 5 results among all 6 initials. The OP expects exactly 5 results per each initial (30 in total). Changing to `limit(30)` wouldn't work either as there would be no way to ensure that of those 30 exactly 5 begin with each letter

Comment: i am getting this result                                                                                                 SELECT `builder_name` FROM `builders_list` WHERE `builder_name` LIKE '%a!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%b!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%c!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%d!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%e!%%' ESCAPE '!' OR `builder_name` LIKE '%f!%%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 5